# Exception on passing a bool to a const std::string&

Tags: c++

Last week I had a funny and thinkable moment... I didn't understand what happened. Maybe someone of you can give me a clue.

I wrote a function like this (simplified):

```
    void read(const std::string& sSource, std::string& sResult, bool bCheck = true)
```

Then later I extended this function with another parameter like this

```
    void read(const std::string& sSource, std::string& sResult, const std::string& sIPAdress, bool bCheck = true)
```

I forgot to change one function call in my program, so it called "read":

```
read("/file/sepp.dat", sResult, false);
```

As you see, I passed a `false` to a `const std::string` reference.

Yes, default parameters are bad, but that's not the point here.

I've got an exception (I don't remember the exact output):

"Can't initialize a std::string with a nullptr" or so...

So there are four questions now, that I can't answer myself:

1.) How can it be, that the compiler didn't emit a warning on this?

2.) Why is the type system unable to find out, the a `bool` should never "go into" a `string` this way?

3.) Why is this happening only to a `const std::string&`, not a `std::string&` parameter? (with a non-`const` `std::string` there is a compiler error)

4.) Is there any possible use of passing a `bool` to a `const std::string` reference that makes the compiler think, this might be right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) An implicit conversion from `bool` to `const char*` is allowed. Unfortunately that is a feature of the language.

2) Because there is an implicit conversion from `bool` to `const char*` and `std::string` has a constructor that takes `const char*` as parameter. It assumes it points to a valid null-terminated string, which is why you see a runtime error.

3) Because the language does not allow to bind temporaries to non-const lvalue references. Id does, however, allow to bind const lvalue references to temporaries.

4) The compiler already thinks it is right, for all the above reasons.

Comment: Wow, a second after I asked, your very adequate answer came in. +1 for that, cool.

Comment: So there isn't a implicit conversion from bool to non-const char*? That's why i've got an compiler error in case of using non-const std::string& as parameter?

Comment: @DirkMausF No, that's not the problem. The problem is you can't bind a temporary to a non-const reference, and when you pass a bool, a temporary `std::string` would have to be made from that bool (via the conversion mentioned above.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but why do you have to rate my question down with -1?

Comment: Hi, this is my first question here, so what is +3/-0 atm?

Comment: @DirkMausF It has 3 upvotes and no downvotes At The Moment. So I'm wondering why you asked "why do you have to rate my question down with -1?"

Comment: C++14 removed the implicit conversion of `false` to a "null pointer constant".